# I don't know, why does it not work (plot)

Tags: pgfplots, plot

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2in,%
left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,%
footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
x tick label style={
    /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
ylabel=Eltérés,
enlargelimits=0.2,
ybar interval=0.8,
]
\addplot 
coordinates {(1,25) (2,8.5)
    (3,7.9) (4,3.8) (5,4.2) (6,7.7) (7,6.8) (8,3.2) (9,15.2) };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add another pair with `(10,...)`.

Comment: very big thank you, you saved my life, I can do my homework :)

Comment: It does work, in the sense that `pgfplots` does as instructed. Are you actually after `ybar`, and not `ybar interval=0.8`?

Comment: You probably wanted an `ybar` and not an `ybar interval`. Read differences in `pgfplots` documentation.

Comment: thank you, everithing is clear, I used ybar interval, because I saw it in an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

So if you want `(9,15.2)` to be shown, add another coordinate or change the plot to be `ybar`(without `interval`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2in,%
left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,%
footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
x tick label style={
    /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
ylabel=Eltérés,
enlargelimits=0.2,
ybar,% interval=0.8,
]
\addplot 
coordinates {(1,25) (2,8.5)
    (3,7.9) (4,3.8) (5,4.2) (6,7.7) (7,6.8) (8,3.2) (9,15.2) };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Works for me............................

[image]

Comment: I want a 9. on the x axis too, with 15.2 paramter