# How do I get the last group out, in this bar chart?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

The last group that contains the year 2014 does not appear

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
x tick label style={
    /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
ylabel=Porcentaje,
enlargelimits=0.15,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
ybar interval=0.7,
]
\addplot 
coordinates {(2012,14.3) (2013,12.0) (2014,16.8)};

\addplot 
coordinates {(2012,15.5) (2013,13.5) (2014,16.9)};

\addplot 
coordinates {(2012,12.8) (2013,9.9) (2014,11.1)};

\addplot 
coordinates {(2012,0.2) (2013,0.3) (2014,0.4)};

\legend{Manufactura,Comercio,Servicios,Minería}
\end{axis}
```

\end{tikzpicture}

[image: Grouped Bar Chart Fail]

Comment: Hi, welcome. You're using `ybar interval`, you should be using `ybar`. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/355862 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163590. Note also that it's always appreciated if you make complete [minimal working examples](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/), i.e. starting with `\documentclass`, containing the necessary packages/definitions (but not more), ending with `\end{document}`. In some cases an MWE is needed to figure out what's wrong, and otherwise it saves time for those who want to test your code to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made only one small mistake. Have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.3,
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        x tick label style={
            /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
        ylabel=Porcentaje,
        enlargelimits=0.15,
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
            anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
        ybar=0.7,       % <-- replaced `ybar interval' by `ybar'
        xtick=data,     % <-- added
    ]
        \addplot coordinates {(2012,14.3) (2013,12.0) (2014,16.8)};

        \addplot coordinates {(2012,15.5) (2013,13.5) (2014,16.9)};

        \addplot coordinates {(2012,12.8) (2013,9.9) (2014,11.1)};

        \addplot coordinates {(2012,0.2) (2013,0.3) (2014,0.4)};

        \legend{Manufactura,Comercio,Servicios,Minería}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]